# Proofs by counter example

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples, integers

Suppose *R* and *S* are relations on the set X.

1. *R* is symmetric → *R'* is antisymmetric
2. *R* and *S* are transitive → *R* ∪ *S* is transitive
3. *R* and *S* are antisymmetric → *R* ∪ *S* is antisymmetric

I'm having trouble thinking of and proving a counter example for these 3. Any ideas or help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I have some hints written up, but it would be nice to see some attempt from you here. #1 especially is quite easy if you just try the first example that comes to mind.

Comment: Please add a definition of the antisymmetry and what $R'$ is